# DQN from scratch not able to learn any environment, no matter parameters using

Tags: python, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, dqn

I've attempted to implement a DQN from scratch, without importing the neural network from a library, and have attempted to get it to work with the Luna Lander environment, however no matter the values for the parameters and even after 600 episodes the reward is always decreasing and frequently less than -300. As no matter the parameters used the issue persists, I must have made an error in how I implemented the algorithm, through I cannot find it.

I have even tried using the parameters values as suggested from this paper [Solving Luna Lander with DQN](https://drawar.github.io/pdfs/lunar_lander.pdf) though that did not solve issues. Initially I was getting issues of exploding gradients so I changed from MSE loss to use huber loss, and while that solved that specific issue the training did not go any better. The adam optimizer was also used to prevent issues from the gradient becoming too small occurring.
My though is that possibly an issue is occurring with how the backpropagation algorithm was implemented however as is my understanding it is done by calculating the layers error by Weight<sup>layer+1</sup> matrix multiplied by Error<sup>layer+1</sup> and all multiplied by the derivative of the layers activation function and updating the models parameters with this matrix multiplied by the previous layers output and the learning rate appears to be correct to me.

I even tested the algorithm on the cartpole environment, but with no luck either, as the reward remained low while the loss kept very small and fluctuating around 0

See my code below

*Import the libraries*

```
import numpy as np
import gym #holds the environments to pick from
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random #for picking a random element
import cv2
from collections import deque #similar to a list, but more efficent as allows efficent appending and poping items from both sides
import time
!pip install gym[box2d] #pick an environment from the box2d library
```

*Setup the model*

```
env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2", render_mode='rgb_array') #setup the Taxi-v3 environment
env.reset()

#print out the initial state of this environment
im = env.render()
plt.imshow(im[0])
```

*Implement the DQN algorithm*

-many different network layouts were also used, such as three hidden layers with 32, 64 and 64 and two hidden layers both with 128 neurons each did not help and only changed how long the model took to train

```
class DQN():
  #initilize all the attributes of this class
  def __init__(self, state_size, action_size, learning_rate, replay_buffer_size, gamma, epsilon, target_update_rate, batch_size, video_episodes):
    self.state_size = state_size
    self.action_size = action_size
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.replay_max_size = replay_buffer_size

    self.replay_buffer = deque(maxlen = replay_buffer_size) # specify the max elements it holds before some get removed

    # define the various hyper parameters
    self.gamma = gamma # amount of value the optimal future reward has 0-1
    self.epsilon = epsilon # used in the e-greedy policy to determine if explotion or exploration is what is to be performed 0-1
    self.target_update_rate = target_update_rate # allow the target networks values to be updated every xxx steps(or episodes)

    self.batch_size = batch_size # size of the random replay buffer batch used in order to ensure limited correlation
    self.video_episodes = video_episodes # the interval for the times it makes the video, as all frames quickly runs out of storage


    # define the two neural networks, ensuring each are the same initially
    self.main_network = None
    self.target_network = None

  def initilize_network(self):
    # define the two neural networks, ensuring each are the same initially
    self.main_network = self.build_network()
    self.target_network = self.build_network()

    # ensure the target network is a copy of the main by giving it the same weights
    self.copy_to_target()

  def build_network(self):
    # the act of building and compiling the network
    # also need to specify the activation function each uses
    model = NN(self.learning_rate)
    model.network = []

    model.add(Dense(number_neurons=self.state_size, activation_value='relu')) # as 8 possible input observations to be tracked
    model.add(Dense(number_neurons=32, activation_value='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(number_neurons=self.action_size, activation_value='linear')) # as four possible output actions

    return model

  # add the elements to the replay buffer
  def update_replay(self, current_state, action_performed, reward, next_state, is_terminal):
    self.replay_buffer.append((current_state, action_performed, reward, next_state, is_terminal))

# determines the action to use at each step of the learning process
  def EGreedyPolicy(self, current_state, current_episode, max_episodes):
    #new_epsilon = max(0.1, (1 - current_episode / max_episodes) * self.epsilon) # linearly decrease the epsilon value towards 0.1
    if random.uniform(0, 1) < self.epsilon:
      action = random.randint(0, self.action_size - 1) # Explore the environment by picking a random action to perform
    else:
      Q_values = self.main_network.predict(current_state) # get all possible action values from the network
      Q_values = np.hstack(Q_values).A1                   # convert into an array so the best action can be found
      action = np.argmax(Q_values, axis=0)                # Exploit learned values to maximize the reward recieved
    return action


  def get_mini_batch(self):
    if len(self.replay_buffer) >= self.batch_size:
      current_batch_size = self.batch_size 
    else:
      current_batch_size = len(self.replay_buffer)
    return random.sample(self.replay_buffer, current_batch_size)


  # train the model to improve its overall policy
  def train(self, env, num_episodes, num_steps):
    total_steps = 0 # used to determine when the target network gets its values updated
    train_frames = [] # save a rendering of each frame of the training process
    
    episode_rewards = []
    episode_losses = []

    while len(self.replay_buffer) < self.replay_max_size:
      terminated = False
      steps_complete = 0

      current_state = env.reset()

      # perform steps of the episode until the agent either terminates or reaches its max step count
      while terminated == False and steps_complete < num_steps:
        chosen_action = self.EGreedyPolicy(current_state, 0, num_episodes)

        next_state, reward, terminated, info = env.step(chosen_action) # perform the chosen action in the environment

        self.update_replay(current_state, chosen_action, reward, next_state, terminated)

        current_state = next_state # update the state
        steps_complete += 1
    
    print("Replay Buffer Full")

    for i in range(0, num_episodes):
      terminated = False
      steps_complete = 0

      current_state = env.reset()

      total_reward = [] # used to calculate the mean accumulative reward for each episode
      total_loss = [] # used to calculate the mean accumulative reward for each episode

      # perform steps of the episode until the agent either terminates or reaches its max step count
      while terminated == False and steps_complete < num_steps:
        chosen_action = self.EGreedyPolicy(current_state, i, num_episodes)

        next_state, reward, terminated, info = env.step(chosen_action) # perform the chosen action in the environment

        self.update_replay(current_state, chosen_action, reward, next_state, terminated)

        # determine the traning data to use and calculate the loss
        mini_batch = self.get_mini_batch()
        if len(self.replay_buffer) >= self.replay_max_size: # only update if the minibatch is full
          loss = self.huber_loss(mini_batch, True)
          total_loss.append(loss)

          if total_steps % self.target_update_rate == 0:
            self.copy_to_target() # every so many steps update the target network
            print("Target Network Updated")

        current_state = next_state # update the state
        steps_complete += 1
        total_steps += 1

        # update the lists for later cross checking and evaluation of the model
        total_reward.append(reward)

        # generate and save the frame of training every xxx episodes
        if i % self.video_episodes == 0 or i == 0:
          img = env.render()[0]
          train_frames.append(img)

      episode_cumulative_reward = np.sum(total_reward) 
      episode_rewards.append(episode_cumulative_reward)
      episode_cumulative_loss = np.mean(total_loss) 
      episode_losses.append(episode_cumulative_loss)
      print("Episode Complete: " + str(i) + ", Reward: " + str(episode_cumulative_reward)+ ", Loss: " + str(episode_cumulative_loss)
      + ", Epsilon: " + str(self.epsilon) + ", Target_Updates: " + str(total_steps)) 
      
      if len(self.replay_buffer) >= self.replay_max_size: # only update if the minibatch is full
        self.epsilon *= 0.9925
        self.epsilon = max(0.1, self.epsilon)

    return train_frames, episode_rewards, episode_losses

# over all of the mini_batches samples determine the error in prediction or its loss using Mean Square Error
  def huber_loss(self, mini_batch, use_derivative = False):
    total_loss = 0
    for i in range(0, len(mini_batch)):
      # determine the target value, which is the current best guess of the actual expected value
      target_value = mini_batch[i][2] # the current reward
      if not mini_batch[i][4]: # if the following state is not terminal get the 
        Q_values = self.target_network.predict(mini_batch[i][3])
        Q_values = np.hstack(Q_values).A1 

        target_value += self.gamma * np.max(Q_values) # the max action's value

      # the current guess of the values the network should generate, based on the batch items values
      index_state = mini_batch[i][0]
      index_action = mini_batch[i][1]
      predicted_value = self.main_network.predict(index_state)[index_action] # get the q-value for all actions in the state and specifically want the one for the action a
      
      loss_gradient = self.main_network.huber_loss(predicted_value, target_value, True) # get the loss for this data points values

      # update the networks parameters based on this loss using gradient descent
      self.main_network.backpropagate(loss_gradient)

      total_loss += loss_gradient
    total_loss /= len(mini_batch)
    return total_loss

  # update the target network by copying over all the main networks parameter values for weights and biases to the target network
  def copy_to_target(self):
    self.target_network.set_weight_bias(self.main_network.get_weight_bias())
```

*Create the neural network*

```
class NN():
  def __init__(self, learning_rate = 0.0001):
    
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate

    self.network = None # a list holding all the layers of the network

  # add a layer to the network
  def add(self, layer):

    # determine the number of input values the layer has so that the size of its weight matrix can be properly determined
    if len(self.network) - 1 >= 0:
      prev_layer = self.network[len(self.network) - 1]
      layer_input_amount = prev_layer.output_amount # use the previous layers output as input into this layer
    else:
      layer_input_amount = layer.output_amount #as the first network layer, no previous layer inputs can be used

    layer.learning_rate = self.learning_rate
    layer.randomize_weight_bias(layer_input_amount) # randomly assign weights and biases initially

    self.network.append(layer)

  # loop through all layers and perform the feed forward method, passing each output to the next as it goes
  def feed_forward(self, input):    
    for layer in self.network:
      input = layer.feed_forward(input)

    return input

  def backpropagate(self, loss_grad):
    for layer in self.network[::-1]:
      loss_grad = layer.backpropagate(loss_grad)

  # based on current values return the output of the network
  def predict(self, input_state):
    input_state = np.vstack(input_state)
    Q_values = self.feed_forward(input_state)
    return Q_values

# converted to huber loss in order to solve exploding gradient problems
  def huber_loss(self, predicted_value, target_value, use_derivative):
    # if the loss is small use MSE
    # if the loss is quite large use MAE(mean absolute error) as this is less sensitive to outliers in the dataset, and as shown when just used MSE exploding gradient occured
    delta = 1 # idea is that this constrains the loss to between 1 and -1

    abs_loss = abs(target_value - predicted_value)

    if use_derivative:
      if abs_loss <= delta:
        loss = 2*(predicted_value-target_value) / 4 # as have 4 seperate data points with the other three's values always being 0 and so would not effect the loss calculations
      else:
        loss = -delta*np.sign(target_value - predicted_value) / 4
    else:
      huber_MSE = 0.5 * (target_value - predicted_value)**2
      huber_MAE = delta * abs_loss - 0.5 * delta**2
      if abs_loss <= delta:
        loss = huber_MSE / 4
      else:
        loss = huber_MAE / 4
    return loss.A1[0] # convert the 1,1 matrix to a scalar

# get all the weights and biases for the network
  def get_weight_bias(self):
    parameters = [[],[]]
    for layer in self.network:
      #if hasattr(layer, "weights"):
      parameters[0].append(layer.weights)
      #if hasattr(layer, "bias"):
      parameters[1].append(layer.bias)

    return parameters

# set all the weights and biases for the network
  def set_weight_bias(self, new_values):
    for i in range(0, len(self.network)):
      #if hasattr(self.network[i], "weights"):
      self.network[i].weights = new_values[0][i]
      #if hasattr(self.network[i], "bias"):
      self.network[i].bias = new_values[1][i]
```

```
class Layer():
    def __init__(self, number_neurons, activation_value):
      self.current_output = None
      self.current_input = None

      self.output_amount = number_neurons

      self.activation_value = activation_value

    def feed_forward(self, input):
      return input

    def backpropagate(self, loss_grad):
      return loss_grad

# the various activation functions the network uses
    def activation(self, value, use_derivative = False):
      if self.activation_value == 'relu':
        return self.relu(value, use_derivative)
      elif self.activation_value == 'linear':
        return self.linear(value, use_derivative)
      else:
        raise Exception('No appropriate activation picked, it must be either linear or relu')

    # in both, when specified used the equations derivative as the back-propogation algorithm is running, otherwise its performing a forward pass and will use the normal function
    
    # normally returns x
    # dertivative returns 1
    def linear(self, value, use_derivative = False):
      if use_derivative:
        for i in range(len(value)):
          for j in range(len(value[i])):      
            value[i][j] = 1

      return value

    # normally returns max(0,x)
    # derivative returns x < 0 = 0, x = 1
    def relu(self, value, use_derivative = False):
      for i in range(len(value)):
        for j in range(len(value[i])):      
          if value[i][j] < 0:
            value[i][j] = 0
          
          elif use_derivative:
            value[i][j] = 1

      return value
```

```
from os import wait
class Dense(Layer):
  # when initilizing the layer need to specify the exact number of output neurons to have and need to know the exact number of inputs as well
  def __init__(self, number_neurons, activation_value):
    super().__init__(number_neurons, activation_value)

    # initilize the weights and biases to random values
    self.weights = None #note that weight is a matrix
    self.bias = None #note that bias is a number

    self.learning_rate = None

    self.first_moment = None
    self.second_moment = None
    self.bias1 = 0.9
    self.bias2 = 0.999
    self.e = 10**-8
    self.time = 1

  def randomize_weight_bias(self, input_amount):
    #give each activation function its own random value type
    if self.activation_value == 'relu':
      self.weights = np.random.rand(self.output_amount, input_amount) * np.sqrt(2/self.output_amount)
    else:
      self.weights = np.random.rand(self.output_amount, input_amount) * 0.01
    self.weights = np.matrix(self.weights, dtype=np.float64, copy = True)
    self.bias = 1 #give biases a large effect
    
    self.first_moment = np.zeros((self.output_amount, input_amount))
    self.second_moment = np.zeros((self.output_amount, input_amount))

  def feed_forward(self, prev_layer_output):
    self.current_input = prev_layer_output
    self.current_output = self.weights * prev_layer_output + self.bias # perform the feed forward operation, producing a matrix of size (x, 1)
    return self.activation(self.current_output)                        # modify the output value by the activation function 


  def backpropagate(self, loss_grad):
    # now using the Adam optimizer with back-propagation method

    if self.output_amount == env.action_space.n:
      error = loss_grad * self.activation(self.current_output, True) # this is the actual error of the last layer of the network
    else:
      error = self.activation(self.current_output, True)
      for i in range(len(loss_grad)):
        for j in range(len(loss_grad[i])):
          error[i][j] = loss_grad[i][j] * error[i][j] 
    
    self.first_moment = self.bias1 * self.first_moment + (1- self.bias1) * error
    self.second_moment = self.bias2 * self.second_moment + (1- self.bias2) * np.power(error, 2)

    m = self.first_moment/(1-np.power(self.bias1, self.time+0.1))
    v = self.second_moment/(1-np.power(self.bias2, self.time+0.1))

    self.weights -= (self.learning_rate * m) / (np.sqrt(v)+self.e)
    self.bias -= np.mean((self.learning_rate * m) / (np.sqrt(v)+self.e))

    self.time += 1

    return self.weights.T * error
```

*Training the agent*

```
dqn = DQN(state_size=env.observation_space.shape[0], action_size=env.action_space.n, learning_rate = 0.0001, replay_buffer_size=10000, gamma = 0.999, epsilon = 1, target_update_rate = 1000, batch_size = 128, video_episodes = 20)

dqn.initilize_network()

train_frames, reward, loss = dqn.train(env, 600, 500)
```